# Is it possible to recognize a flickering LED from its technical data?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led

LEDs often flicker and I hate it. You rarely see it directly, but you can recognize it when you do fast movements with your hand or so, while the LED is the only light source. The movement then does not appear smooth.

Focussing on LED without driver, can you recognize just from the technical data, if an LED flickers? Is there something hidden in the numbers of watt, lumen, or something which might gives a hint whether an LED flickers or not?

Would be great, because I am sick of buying and being disappointed...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about electronics and not home improvement.

Comment: The answers are making it so.  The question is a DIY homeowner trying to get LED screw-in bulb replacements that aren't crap, so dead on-point for this forum IMO.

Answer (score 1):

> **Is there something hidden in the numbers of watt, lumen, or something which might gives a hint whether an LED flickers or not?**

No.

Flicker of LED based lamps is dependent on technical details of the implementation of the driver electronics. Any flickering LED won't flicker if driven with a continuous stable regulated DC current.

Comment: The technical details are about the entire screw-in bulb, including LED, the driver and whatever, right? So I cannot guess from these details how continuous and stable the DC current?

Answer (score 1):

The issue you see is not the LED component itself that has specs to be a "flickering candidate". It is instead related to how the component is designed into the product. There are three main reasons you will see flickering.

1. Many times if a product has many LEDs the circuitry inside (these days almost always a microcontroller) will reduce the number of signal wires needed to drive all the LEDs by time slicing and driving the LED only a percentage of the time. For example four specific LEDs may share just single signal wire that specifies the on/off state for the LEDs and then applies that to each of the four LEDs in turn so that each only shows its actual ON state for 25% of the total time. Separate circuitry using other signal wires determines which of the four is on at a given time. Using this scheme it is possible to support four LEDs with two signal wires, eight LEDs with three signal wires, 16 LEDs with four signal wires and so forth. The potential for visible flicker in these cases can be reduced if the rate that the time slicing applied is boosted up to beyond the human perception range.
2. Sometimes an LED is driven with a signal known as a PWM (pulse width modulation) that can be varied by the product controller. The variance comes in to play with how long the LED is left on in a given span of time. This is used to control the net brightness of the LED (or in some cases the net power consumed by the LED). The "given span of time" is sometimes a slow enough rate that it is noticeable by the human eye such as you have seen in conditions of fast movement.
3. Then there are these cheap LED lighting products designed with a whole slew of LEDs all connected up together in what is called a parallel configuration. These will be driven from a single source of current to all the LEDs. When the battery to such product starts to get depleted the voltage to the driving circuitry will lower. This can cause some LEDs in the large parallel group to flicker because of a variance of the ON bias voltage characteristic between the different LEDs. I won't go into the technical details of why this happens here but can say it is a totally annoying behavior of cheaply designed products. Better products will be designed so that each LED has its own source of current from the battery. This isolation can be as simple as a separate resistor for each LED.

Comment: Ok, yes, but I am buying the entire product, which includes the LED the driver and whatever inside the bulb. And the technical details are not about the LED component itself (maybe some, but not all), but on the product. I am actually not interested in the LED it self, but in the ready to use screw-in bulb. Are there technical details about the product which might give a hint?